# Spring-Boot and Kafka : How to handle broker not available?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

While the spring-boot app is running and if I shutdown the broker completely ( both kafka and zookeeper ) I am seeing this warn in console for infinite amount of time.

> [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1]
>   WARN  o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Consumer
>   clientId=consumer-1, groupId=ResponseReceiveConsumerGroup]
>   Connection to node 2147483647 could not be established. Broker may not
>   be available.

Is there a way in Spring Boot to handle this gracefully instead of infinite logs on console ?

Comment: I believe those are kafka library logs, when consumer or producer starts it will try to identify brokers for every time intervals

Comment: Increase the `reconnect.backoff.ms`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increase the `reconnect.backoff.ms` property (see [Kafka docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/)).

The default is only 50ms.

Comment: Thanks, Instead of this constant back off , How would we handle longer broker outages ?

Comment: That's really a question for the Kafka folks since it's out of Spring's control. Fortunately, the new 2.0.0 kafka-clients no longer block when this occurs (supported by spring-kafka 2.2 which will be released late September/early October, 2.2..0.M1 milestone is available now). From a Spring perspective, you will then be able to `stop()` the message listener container(s). All that being said, with the whole resiliency model for Kafka (multiple replicas) the intention is that the broker should never be "down".