# Why won't Maven Clean Install complete if Kafka and Zookeeper are not running?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

In an effort to learn `Apache Kafka`, I’ve developed a `Spring Boot` application that sends messages to a `Kafka` topic if I send a POST request to a controller that calls a `KafkaTemplate` send method.  I’m running Ubuntu 19.04 and successfully set up and installed `Kafka` and `Zookeeper` locally.  Everything works fine.

The problem happens when I shut down either `Zookeeper` or `Kafka`.  If I do this then on startup the `Kafka AdminClient` of my application periodically tries to find a broer but sends this message to the console

```
Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

I implemented the fixes suggested here [Kafka + Zookeeper: Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47677549/kafka-zookeeper-connection-to-node-1-could-not-be-established-broker-may-no) and here [Spring-Boot and Kafka : How to handle broker not available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51794192/spring-boot-and-kafka-how-to-handle-broker-not-available).  But if I run a `maven clean install` then the build never finishes if `Zookeeper` and `Kafka` aren’t running.  Why is this and is there a way to configure the application so that it checks for `Kafka` availability on startup and gracefully handles when the service is unavailable?

Here is my service class that calls the `KafkaTemplate`

```
@Autowired
public PingMessageServiceImpl(KafkaTemplate kafkaTemplate, KafkaTopicConfiguration kafkaTopicConfiguration) {
    this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
    this.kafkaTopicConfiguration = kafkaTopicConfiguration;
}

@Override
public void sendMessage(String message) {
    log.info(String.format("Received following ping message %s", message));

    if (!isValidPingRequest(message)) {
        log.warn("Received invalid ping request");
        throw new InvalidPingRequestException();
    }
    log.info(String.format("Sending message=[%s]", message));
    ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(kafkaTopicConfiguration.getPingTopic(), message);
    future.addCallback(buildListenableFutureCallback(message));
}

private boolean isValidPingRequest(String message) {
    return "ping".equalsIgnoreCase(message);
}

private ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, String>> buildListenableFutureCallback(String message) {
    return new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, String>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, String> result) {
            log.info(String.format("Sent message=[%s] with offset=[%d]", message, result.getRecordMetadata().offset()));
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
            log.info(String.format("Unable to send message=[%s] due to %s", message, ex.getMessage()));
        }
    };
}
```

Here is the configuration class that I use to extract configuration properties for Kafka from the properties file

```
@NotNull(message = "bootstrapAddress cannot be null")
@NotBlank(message = "bootstrapAddress cannot be blank")
private String bootstrapAddress;

@NotNull(message = "pingTopic cannot be null")
@NotBlank(message = "pingTopic cannot be blank")
private String pingTopic;

@NotNull(message = "reconnectBackoffMs cannot be null")
@NotBlank(message = "reconnectBackoffMs cannot be blank")
@Value("${kafka.reconnect.backoff.ms}")
private String reconnectBackoffMs;

@Bean
public KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin() {
    Map<String, Object> configurations = new HashMap<>();
    configurations.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    configurations.put(AdminClientConfig.RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, reconnectBackoffMs);
    return new KafkaAdmin(configurations);
}

@Bean
public NewTopic pingTopic() {
    return new NewTopic(pingTopic, 1, (short) 1);
}

@PostConstruct
private void displayOnStartup() {
    log.info(String.format("bootstrapAddress is %s", bootstrapAddress));
    log.info(String.format("reconnectBackoffMs is %s", reconnectBackoffMs));
}
```

Comment: do you have any test's, i would like to see if you have any

Comment: I have plenty of tests for other classes in the application but none for the service that uses Kafka.

Comment: are those integration test  annotated with `@SpringBootTest`?

Comment: Some of them are, yes

Comment: That is the issue, when you load `ApplicationContext` during integration test, kafka Beans `KafkaAdmin`, `KafkaTemplate` will try to connect with kafka server, you can simply mock those to avoid such type of scenarios

Comment: Thank you, I understand.  Is there a way to mock the `Kafka` instance so that the Beans will connect to it?  Or is there a way to tell the integration tests to ignore loading the `Kafka` beans?

Comment: yes you can use spring embedded Kafka server but still there is a work around with it, i will say just mock `KafkaTemplate` if producing  and `KafkaAdmin` client you should be good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have any `Spring-boot` integration test while loading the `ApplicationContext` spring kafka beans like `KafakTemplate`,`KafkaAdmin` will try to connect the kafka server with the properties specified in `yml` or `properties` file

So to avoid this you can use [spring-embedded-kafka-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54754662/spring-kafka-integration-testing-with-embedded-kafka), so that kafka beans will connect to embedded server during test execution.

Or simple you can just mock the `KafakTemplate` and `KafkaAdmin` beans using `@MockBean` annotation in the integration test cases

Comment: I don't normally prefer testing using embedded stuff. I would rather run a docker for the actual thing for integration testing.

Comment: If he is not testing anything related to Kafka, i will prefer to mock @PrashantPandey